# Verify SES email address through CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-cdk

I wan to verify an email address from my CDK itself so that when my stack is deployed tto some other regions this verification is automatically triggered, rather than going to AWS console and doing it manually.

Answer (score 11):

You can either do that using `AwsCustomResource` from `@aws-cdk/custom-resources` and it looks similar to the example that you can find here for validating a domain: [Custom Resource Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/custom-resources-readme.html#custom-resource-examples).

**Verify email using TypeScript**

I'm adjusting the example here for your use case:

```js
const verifyDomainIdentity = new AwsCustomResource(this, 'VerifyDomainIdentity', {
  onCreate: {
    service: 'SES',
    action: 'verifyEmailIdentity',
    parameters: {
      EmailAddress: 'your@example.com'
    },
    physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of('verify-email-address')
  },
  policy: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({resources: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE}) // This does not work somehow with SES or maybe I did something wrong :-(
});
```

Unfortunately this does not work out of the box because somehow the generated policy includes an `email:` prefix instead of `ses:` and you need to provide your own policy. But there's an alternative below.

**Using an existing CDK Construct with TypeScript**

The other alternative is to use a CDK Construct which is already doing that for you. I recently ran into the same problem like you and I've published a CDK Construct for that: [`ses-verify-identities`](https://github.com/seeebiii/ses-verify-identities). You can then do it like this:

```js
new VerifySesEmailAddress(this, 'SesEmailVerification', {
  emailAddress: 'hello@example.org'
});
```

You can find the source code of the CDK construct [here](https://github.com/seeebiii/ses-verify-identities/blob/main/lib/verify-ses-email-address.ts) in case you are interested. The same is possible for [verifying domains](https://github.com/seeebiii/ses-verify-identities/blob/main/lib/verify-ses-domain.ts).

Comment: This is the reason idiomatic form doesn't work.
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4533